# where can I find the chef's core resources?

Tags: resources, chef-infra

I'm very new to chef and the chef version I'm using is

```
  [root@localhost ~]# chef --version
  Chef Development Kit Version: 1.3.43
  chef-client version: 12.19.36
  delivery version: master (dd319aa632c2f550c92a2172b9d1226478fea997)
  berks version: 5.6.4
  kitchen version: 1.16.0
```

when I create cookbook using

```
   knife cookbook create COOKBOOK #I'm able to see libraries directory
```

whereas If create cookbook using

```
   chef generate cookbook COOKBOOK #I'm unable to find libraries directory
```

Now my question is I want to create custom resource for myself, where I have to store my custom resource?

can I store them in chef's core resources directory? If yes, then how to find out the chef's core resources directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom resources go in the `resources/` folder in your cookbook. You cannot edit the core resources as those live in the Chef code base, not your cookbook.

Comment: I mean if you think it's something important enough to include in core you can fork the `chef/chef` repository on GitHub and send us a pull request. This is not something I would expect a new user to do right away.

Comment: The reason why I want to shift them to chef code base is: 


whenever I create a new cookbook I have to copy them to the resources each time I create a new cookbook.

I dont want to copy them everytime when I create a new cookbook.
I want them to be placed in general location and just go on creating the cookbooks and enjoy

Comment: Cookbooks can depend on other cookbooks so you would put those in some base library cookbook and then depend on that in your other cookbooks.

Comment: please could you tell me how to create the base library cookbook and tell the chef that this is my base library cookbook?

Comment: It's just like any other cookbook, nothing special other than how you think about using them. To depend on a cookbook from another add `depends "othername"` to the `metadata.rb`.

Comment: do you mean some thing like this in metadata.rb?

`name 'foo'`
`maintainer 'The Authors'`
`depends COOKBOOK_NAME`

Comment: The name you are depending on needs to be in quotes, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally custom resource live under the `resources` directory.

However if you need to write helpers, `library` will still be used.

Chef Docs for Custom Resources: https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html
Further in-depth information can be found here: https://docs.chef.io/dsl_custom_resource.html

An example of custom resource usage can be found here with integration tests https://github.com/sous-chefs/samba